# Find upper and lower bounds to the function $f(n)=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)$ where $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: number-theory, optimization

Find upper and lower bounds to the function $$f(n)=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot\ldots\cdot (2n-1)\;,$$ where $n\in\Bbb N$.

I got $$\left(\frac{2n-1}e\right)^{(2n-1)/2}$$ as lower bound and

$$\left(\frac{2n+1}e\right)^{(2n+1)/2}$$

as upper bound.

Just wanted to know if any better bounds were there..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The factor multiplies all uneven integers up to $n$ (including)?

Comment: By upper bound, you mean a fixed real number $M > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is that right? In that case, this function has no upper bound, so I am guessing that this is not what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using factorials, we can write
$$ f(n) =\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$$
and then using Stirling's $n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$ find
$$\tag1 f(n)\approx \frac{(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{2^nn^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}=\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^n\cdot \sqrt 2$$
so your $f(n)$ grows quite fast (not surprisingly). For an explicit upper/lower bound function, use explicit bounds for Stirling's approximation.

**Edit:** It seems you essentially did that to obtain your bounds with *one* additional term in the Stirling approximation. Do find something better one might try to look at higher order terms in STirling, but admittedly the expressions turn out ugly (and probably not very helpful)

---

Note that we can also observe that $f(n)={2n\choose n}\cdot \frac{n!}{2^n}$ and then from ${2n\choose n}\le (1+1)^{2n}=4^n$ find $$\tag2f(n)\le 2^nn! $$
as a simple upper bound (and it's only ba a factor $\approx\sqrt {\pi n}$ bigger than the estimate in $(1)$).